# How to change the path after a domain to be more friendly?

Tags: javascript, html, url

Is it possible to change the path after a domain in the browser address bar?

for example, I am on `www.mydomain.com` and by hitting a link it goes to `www.mydomain.com/path/another_path/`.

How can I change this to `www.mydomain.com/new_path`

Thanks for helping.

Comment: can you make your question more specific ? are you using a specific Framework or project/CMS ? do you know if you are using apache, or nginx or somthing else ? ...

Comment: i am using a dedicated server with nginx.

Comment: I want to rename a path to something else to make it look more friendly? thanx

Comment: Good, So does my answer below helped you? If yes you can accept it as ansewer, else if you need further details don't hesitate

Comment: i am about to create my own website, i am new to nginx, php and html. i looked at your link given for the nginx rewrite rule, but it seems that i dont get it to work..

Comment: can you share what you have tested ?

Comment: i am trying to rename `domain.mydomain.com/path1/path2/` to `domain.mydomain.com/path1/media=recently_added` with the rewrite rule `rewrite ^(/path1/.*)/path2/*$ $1/media=recently_added/ last;` in the location block of path1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your implementation or the project/framework you are using.

First thing to check is, does the framework you are using provide an **url_rewrite feature**.

If you are coding from scratch and that you can edit server config like apache/nginx then you can configure a 3xx redirect from new to old url like below :

For nginx see : https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/

For apache : https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish this with a URL Rewrite rule in your project web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Rewrite">
            <match url="path/another_path" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="https://example.com/new_path" />
        </rule>
  </rules>
    </rewrite>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <clear />
                <add value="index.html" />
                <add value="Default.htm" />
                <add value="Default.asp" />
                <add value="index.htm" />
                <add value="iisstart.htm" />
                <add value="default.aspx" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: It depends on the fact he is using the same project structure as yours using web.config.
Can you reference from where comes your web.config ?